# Ordinary chemical means

Tags: elements

What is the meaning of *ordinary chemical means* in the following:

> An element may be defined as a pure substance that can not be
>   decomposed by ordinary chemical means.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially it means that you exclude the possibility of splitting an element even further via nuclear means.